# drawable area in HTML bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing an online repair form and I'd like to have a drawable area where the client could sign (with a capacitive pen on a tablet) the form.

Is it possible to have it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny you should ask this just now. I was just reading about Jennifer Dewalt's "180 Websites in 180 days" project, and noticed one of her's was drawing :)

See here: http://jenniferdewalt.com/node/one_drawing

And more about Jennifer's project: http://jenniferdewalt.com/